# How can I proper render a list using dynamic values of keys?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble rendering my list in the following way. I use a state called currentListKey to track the key of the list. This state is set when adding an item to the list:

```
  const addToList = () => {
    const selectedOption = optionsList.find((option) => option._id === value.value);
    setFormValues((prevValues) => {
      const newList = prevValues[inputKey].filter((list) => typeof list !== "string");
      newList.push(selectedOption);
      return {
        ...prevValues,
        [inputKey]: newList,
      };
    });

    setSelectedOptions([...selectedOptions, selectedOption]);
    setCurrentListKey(inputKey);
    setValue(null);
  };
```

inputKey is the current key, and when I add it, it determines the form key and renders the list like this:

```
 {formValues[currentListKey] && formValues[currentListKey].length > 0 && (
        <ul>
          {formValues[currentListKey]?.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={index}>
                {item.name}
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setFormType(nextForm);
                    setFormStates((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [currentForm]: formValues }));
                    setSelectedItem(item);
                    setListItem(item);
                    setPrevListKey(currentListKey);
                  }}>
                  Configure
                </button>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setFormValues((prevState) => ({
                      ...prevState,
                      [currentListKey]: prevState[currentListKey].filter((_e, i) => i !== index),
                    }));
                    setSelectedOptions((prevState) => prevState.filter((option) => option._id !== item._id));
                  }}>
                  Remove
                </button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      )}
```

When clicking the configure button, it sets prevListKey as the currentKey so that when I am on the next form and go back or save, it renders the list with the correct key. That's why I also have setCurrentListKey(prevListKey) in the save function.

```
  const handleSave = (listKey) => {
    const index = formStates[prevForm][listKey]?.findIndex((item) => item === listItem);
    if (index !== -1) {
      setFormStates((prevState) => {
        let newFormValues = { ...formValues };
        for (let key in newFormValues) {
          if (formInputs.find((input) => input.key === key && input.type === "reactSelect")) {
            newFormValues[key] = newFormValues[key].value;
          } else if (formInputs.find((input) => input.key === key && input.type === "reactSelectListArray")) {
            newFormValues[key] = newFormValues[key];
          }
        }

        const prevListIndex = prevState[prevForm][prevListKey].findIndex((prevListItem) => prevListItem._id === formValues._id);

        if (prevListIndex !== -1) {
          prevState[prevForm][prevListKey][prevListIndex] = { ...prevState[prevForm][prevListKey][prevListIndex], ...newFormValues };
        }

        return {
          ...prevState,
        };
      });
    }
    setCurrentListKey(prevListKey);
  };
```

In other words, when I save and go back to the previous form, the list is correctly rendered. However, when clicking to configure an item to go to the next form, the list with the added item does not render because the currentListKey is not being set for that form unless I add an item. What could I do to render the list with the correct key not only when adding but also when calling the form or clicking configure? Do I need to create a new state? Can I achieve this with the existing states?